# Acer Aspire A315-51-31GK vs. Acer Aspire A315-51-380T

Tags: laptop

Looking at the specs of these two laptops, they are essentially identical.  Any idea what are differences between these two models?

Comment: What do you plan to do with these laptops, should you decide to pick one of the two? Do you have each one in a different configuration to the other?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking for a computer hardware recommendation. Finding differences between two products is not what this site is here for.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR: They're basically identical. I think it may be a case of switching the part number for a different retailer.

Acer even uses the exact same images to represent them on the product pages, down to the URL.

```
       |    A315-51-31GK |     A315-51-380T
       |–––––––––––––––––|–––––––––––––––––
  MSRP |         $399.99 |             $349
Height |           0.85" |            0.82"
```

The A315-51-31GK appears to be sold at [Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834316147), [the Intel Store](https://www.intel.com/buy/us/en/product/laptops/acer-laptop-aspire-3-a315-51-31gk-intel-core-i3-7th-gen-7100u-240-ghz-4-606108). [Microcenter](http://www.microcenter.com/product/484041/aspire_3_a315-51-31gk_156_laptop_computer_-_black), [SuperBiiz](https://www.superbiiz.com/detail.php?p=AC-A3151GK), [Jet](https://jet.com/product/detail/350e1158bc8f402794f000ab74b2e8bd), and [Amazon](http://a.co/aVMmxd7), while the A315-51-380T appears to be sold at [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Acer-A315-51-380T-15-6-Laptop-7th-Gen-Intel-Core-i3-7100U-4GB-DDR4-1TB-HDD-Windows-10-Home/677478400) and [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077WNR92V).

My best guess is this is a case of Acer using different part numbers to prevent price matching between certain stores.  Amazon doesn't directly price match, so carrying both doesn't hurt them. It seems strange though that Walmart and Jet (who is owned by Walmart) would carry different products though.